# Bibtex: How to start numbering citations from only a specific page?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

In my thesis, I am using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` so that the references will be ordered in the order of their appearance. In my Acknowledgements (which comes well before the introduction chapter), I need to cite some journal. Hence the first citation in the introduction chapter will not start from '1'! I need bibtex to start numbering only from the introduction chapter. Any help to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve: You use a numeric citation style, yet you don't want some of the citation callouts -- those generated in the Acknowledgments part of the document -- to be numbered. If they shouldn't be numbered, how should they be marked? Or should there be no citation callouts at all for these few citations? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry for the confusion. Werner suggested a solution for my problem. You may see his suggestion to get a more clear idea about my problem. But the issue I face now is that Werner's solution is showing error in my document (please see my comment to Werner).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With every call to `\cite`, LaTeX writes to the `.aux` file. All we have to do is mimic `\cite` *without* this writing feature:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
\@article{lorem,author={Lorem Ipsum}}
\@article{ipsum,author={Ipsum Lorem}}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
% Partly taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx
\newcommand{\citenocite}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{b@#1}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}
    \G@refundefinedtrue
    \@latex@warning
      {Citation `#1' on page \thepage \space undefined}}
    {\mbox{[\csname b@#1\endcsname]}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citenocite{ipsum} \cite{lorem} \cite{ipsum}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Though I was able to compile your code, I got compilation error while incorporating this to my document. I added the 'newcommand' in my preamble and while compiling with latex I got the following error. 

Acknowledgements
--------------------------------------------------------
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.17 }
      
? 

The Error is pointing to my Acknowledgements section where I used '\citenocite' . If I replace '\citenocite' with '\cite', it is compiling without any error.

Comment: @Sooraj: Did you include the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair around the `\newcommand`? If yes, then please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem, as I don't know what exactly might be causing the error(s). Perhaps your document class is the main cause, yet I don't even know that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to include \makeatletter...\makeatother pair!